# XSRF-TOKEN not updated when using IISExpress and localhost

Tags: asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

.Net Core api layer and .Net Core MVC w/ Angular2 front end. Locally, they are running in different website (localhost:xxx1 and localhost:xxx2) and published, the api is running in a sub directory of the frontend.

I've set up the .Net Core Antiforgery like so:

in the ConfigureServices section:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
        });
```

in the Configure section:

```
app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
            return next(context);
        });
```

When i initially launch the sites and browse to the website in Chrome, I do get the 2 Antiforgery tokens (.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xxxx and the XSRF-TOKEN) and when I make a get/post/etc call I see the x-xsrf-token header is added to the call.

The problem is on each call, the api returns a new XSRF-TOKEN cookie but locally my cookie is not updated, it always contains the original value. When published online, this doesn't happen, the cookie updates every time.

I've tried setting the sites up locally to use localhost.somedomain.com but that didn't work.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong or how to get it working locally?

Comment: Could you just add into your question in which project you have added anti-forgery. I have a feeling you have added it into your web project, whereas it should actually be inside your API project. I should also note that the cookie does not need to update, it can be used for multiple calls.

Comment: The anti-forgery code is in the web api. i figured it out with the answer below

Answer (score 0):

The issue on my local machine was that I was running each app in its own IIS Express (localhost:xxx1 and localhost:xxx2). 
I ended up setting IIS up to host .net core following this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis) and i'm getting the expected result.